Discrete Random Variables Formulas
A certain system can experience three different types of defects. Let Ai​, i = 1, 2, 3 be the event that the system has a defect of type i. Suppose that P(A1​)=0.17, P(A2​)=0.07, P(A3​)=0.13, P(A1​∪A2​)=0.18, P(A2​∪A3​)=0.18, P(A1​∪A3​)=0.19, and P(A1​∩A2​∩A3​)=0.01. Let the random variable X be the number of defects that are present.

Calculate P(X=1)
Calculate P(X=2)
Calculate P(X=3)
Find E(X)
Find V(X)
Find standard deviation of X

P(X=0) is 0.81 but I am not sure why, unless it's because 1-0.19=0.81, in which case X=1 would equal 0.19, but it does not.
For P(X=1) and P(X=2) I have tried the calculations below from another thread on this site, but the answers are incorrect.
Pr(=1)=Pr(1)+Pr(2)+Pr(3)−2[Pr(1∩2)+Pr(1∩3)+Pr(2∩3)]+3Pr(1∩2∩3)
(.17+.07+.13)-2*((.17*.07)+(.17*.13)+(.07*.13))+3*0.01=0.3138
Pr(=2)=Pr(1∩2)+Pr(1∩3)+Pr(2∩3)−3Pr(1∩2∩3)
((0.170.07)+(0.170.13)+(0.070.13))-(3.01)= 0.0131
Which random variable distribution formula should I be using?

The distribution is already given to you - you just have to work it out with inclusion-exclusion. It just happens it isn't a "special" one you know like binomial, geometric, ...

@SeanRoberson I have successfully found everything except V(X) and std dev of X. If Variance=np(1-p) what are n and p here?

No - that only applies for a binomial random variable, but this is clearly not binomial! You must use the definition of variance, or rather, $V(X) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2.$

What is the formula for P(X=0)? @SeanRoberson

I am thinking P(x=0)=1-P(A union B union C)=1-0.19=0.81
